# Fixed effects model for surface growth

Tags: fixed-effects-model, splines

I am trying to fully understand and reproduce the paper [Normative brain size variation and brain shape diversity in humans](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6394/1222), in which the authors have used brain surface measurements from many different subjects with different brain sizes to compute a scaling factor for each vertex on the brain mesh that describes the increase/decrease in surface area at that anatomical location relative to a given increase in the whole brain surface.

In the Methods section, which is available in the [Supplementary Materials](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2018/05/30/science.aar2578.DC1/aar2578_Reardon_SM.pdf), p4, the authors write:

> Vertex-wise areal scaling with total cortical area was estimated using
>   a semi-parametric  spline  regression  model  that  simultaneously 
>   incorporated  effects  of  age  and sex  on  vertex  area  (41, 42). 
>   The  scaling  relationships  presented  in  our  results,  were
>   estimated using the following fixed-effects model:
>
> Log10(vertex_area) ~ s(age, by=sex) + ß1[log10(total_area)],     [1]
>
> where s(age, by=sex) denotes a fixed-effect thin plate spline basis
>   estimated for each  sex. [...] The ß1 coefficient from model [1] provides > an estimate of how area at each cortical vertex scales with total
>   cortical size.

I would like to implement that model (preferably in Python, Matlab or GNU R), but I am struggling with the part `s(age, by=sex) denotes a fixed-effect thin plate spline basis estimated for each sex`.

How could I compute such a fixed-effect thin plate spline basis, given observations of the position of the respective surface point for a number of subjects (and their age+sex)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **mgcv** package in R has a *gamm* function which will provide what you need as it can incorporate so-called *factor smooth interactions*, which allow the smooth, nonlinear effect of one continuous variable such as age to be different across the levels of a categorical variable such as sex. See for example:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/smooth.construct.fs.smooth.spec.html

https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/

and especially

http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/~jvanrij/Tutorial/GAMM.html.

You'll probably need to specify your model along these lines:

```
gamm(log10(vertex_area) ~ s(age, by = sex, bs = "ts") +     
                          log10(total_area), 
                          data = YourData)
```

In fact, you could also use the bam() function of mgcv instead of the gamm() function, which is suitable for large data sets, as illustrated in the last of the 3 links I provided.

Comment: Thanks, the R functions and the links helped me to get started and let me into the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome, @spirit! 

Comment: @spirit: Please check out this awesome, hot-off-the-press pre-print by Gavin Simpson and his colleagues: https://peerj.com/preprints/27320.pdf. It's an excellent resource!